# android textview links clickable using Html.fromHtml

Tags: android, html, hyperlink, tracking, clickable

I have textview in my app. I have a string which I set in the textview.
The string is HTML string which has lots of html like images, bold and italics.
I used code as follows:

```
content.setText(Html.fromHtml(articledet.toString(), imgGetter, null));
```

I just want the links should be click-able. I achieved that easily. What I want when user clicks on the link, link should be opened in browser but I also want to track what external links where clicked.
i.e. On click of link, I should be able to write URL in a file.
I can do that using spanned. But if I used spanned then, I have load images, that will stop working.
Please help me with this.